# Notation for all k-tuples that can be constructed from a set

Tags: notation

Is there a generally accepted notation for a $k$-tuple that is constructed from a set? I have a set $\mathcal{A}$, and need to sum over all possible $k$-tuples (denoted $t_k$). Right now, I'm using set-notation like so:
$$
\sum_{t_k\subseteq\mathcal{A}} ...
$$
Because the $t_k$ aren't sets, I think this notation is not formally correct. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: The set of $k$-tuples from $A$ is simply $A^k$.

Comment: Seriously??? That, I did not know...

Comment: Seriously. The Cartesian product of $k$ copies of $A$ is exactly the set of $k$-tuples of elements of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cartesian product is your answer.
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}^{k} = \mathcal{A} \times \cdots \times \mathcal{A} = \{ (t_{1},\ldots, t_{k}) \, | \, t_{j} \in \mathcal{A} \textrm{ for } 1 \leq j \leq k \}.
\end{equation}
In the case that $\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, such $k$-tuples are often called multi-indices,since they are used in the notation for multivariate partial derivatives.

Comment: Thanks, such a simple answer...